# Sql - count into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
 num | type
-----+------
 123 | 3
 123 | 2
 123 | 3
 123 | 2
 124 | 3
 124 | 1
 124 | 3
 124 | 3
```

I want to group by the `num` column, and have a column counting each distinct type (I know all the possible values here in advance). So I would get:

```
 num | 1 | 2 | 3
-----+---+---+---
 123 | 0 | 2 | 2
 124 | 1 | 0 | 3
```

Is this possible with SQL? I am using MySql.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT `num`,
    SUM(type = 1) as `1`, 
    SUM(type = 2) as `2`, 
    SUM(type = 3) as `3`
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `num`
```

Comment: That's certainly more concise than `sum(case when type = 1 then 1 end)` !  +1

Comment: @Andomar - It certainly is.  Although I can't express a strong/clear reason, I actually don't like using that type of behaviour.  I'd up-vote `SUM(IF(type=1, 1, 0))` though.  Does anyone else have an opinion on whether `SUM(type=1)` is better or worse than `SUM(IF(type =1, 1, 0))`?

Comment: @Dems: I like the short version better. But it is good to have an alternative mentioned in your comment.