# DB2 SQL count into multiple columns

Tags: sql, db2

i have a situation similar to this: [Sql - count into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240357)

i'll break it down again here

i have a table with these values:

```
 num | type
-----+------
 123 | 3
 123 | 2
 123 | 3
 123 | 2
 124 | 3
 124 | 1
 124 | 3
 124 | 3
```

i want to group by the `num` column, and have a column counting each distinct type. so i would get:

```
 num | 1 | 2 | 3
-----+---+---+---
 123 | 0 | 2 | 2
 124 | 1 | 0 | 3
```

the top solution on that question was:

```
SELECT `num`,
    SUM(type = 1) as `1`, 
    SUM(type = 2) as `2`, 
    SUM(type = 3) as `3`
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `num`
```

when i try this, i get an error saying

> An unexpected token "=" was found following "LECT NUM, SUM(type". Expected tokens may include: "CONCAT". SQLSTATE=42601

can somebody point me towards a workable sql query for db2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in the other answer was for MySQL, you should try the following which uses the `CASE` syntax:

```
select num,
  sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Type1,
  sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Type2,
  sum(case when type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Type3
from yourtable
group by num
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c38c/1) (SQL Server demo)